# NPM Package from custom React Hook and React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-hooks, react-component

I am relatively new to NPM Library Development and I am having a bit of a trouble consuming the library.

What I am trying to do is to export a **React Hook** and a **React Component**.
The Hook and the Component work well when I define and use them whithin my Application, however exporting them results in issues mentioned bellow.

Here is my `package.json`

```json
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.14",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.9",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.11",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  }
```

Here is my entry file:

```js
// index.ts
export { useCustomHook } from './hooks/customHook'
export { default as CustomComponent } from './components/CustomComponent'
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'index.ts'),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
  }
}
```

## Questions / Issues

1. When I import and use my `useCustomHook` I get a
   `TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable`. How can I avoid that?
2. Can I avoid using `react`and `react-dom` as `devDependencies` since I already have them in `peerDependencies`

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out:
the simplest solution is to ditch `webpack` and use `rollup` instead. Then everything is pretty straight forward.